# Android how to cast as a Button

Tags: android, button

Hey,
So im working on this code and I need to cast a `findViewById(R.id.foo)` as a Button in a parameter. What would be the least memory consuming way? Or should I change the parameter to take View instead of a Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button fooButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.foo);
```

Comment: We've all asked stupid questions. :-) Luckily, SO is typically forgiving.